# Can I use ADB with USB Network Gate?

Tags: adb, usb, usb-debugging, remote-control, remote-access

I have a colleague who cannot obtain the kind of Android device we need for our project. He would like to own such a device to test our project with `adb` and similar tools, but to reiterate, his obtainment of this physical Android device is not possible. So the only solution we could think of is to have him remotely access *my* device from *his* computer.

[USB Network Gate](https://www.eltima.com/products/usb-over-ethernet/) is an application that facilitates this kind of functionality. I decided to try it out on my LAN to see if it could solve the problem. Unfortunately, `adb` is having some issues.

In my setup, both desktop machines are running macOS 10.13.4. I am able to share my Android device on a given port and I can even connect to that device just fine from the remote host in my LAN. However, when I try to use `adb` I see that it says the device is offline:

```
$ adb devices    
List of devices attached
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
69c98243    offline
```

Any `adb` command that I try to run also complains that the device is offline. Moreover, the usual prompts on the phone about whether to trust the computer and the "Connect to PC" options do ***not*** come up. I assume that USB Network Gate is somehow upsetting `adb`, but I do not know why.

It is very strange since the rest of the host's system shows that the USB device *is* connected. So I know that the phone is connected to the remote host, but `adb` does not like the connection for some reason. How can I fix this problem so that I can use `adb` on a device connected via USB Network Gate?

Comment: This is a really amazing opportunity for Android developers right now who may need remote access at some point with the https://bundlehunt.com/ deal at basically $150 off right now and thus getting it at under $10 USD!